# SwiftUI 3.0 XCode13 B3 Executing the LocationButton will result in Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)

Tags: swiftui, cllocationmanager, swift5, location-button

When I run LocationButton on B3 simulator of XCode13, I get Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)
When the button is pressed
Detecting errors with delegate func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
The list is as follows, I think the cause is Plist.
I don't know the relationship between Plist and iOS14.
Plist is not used.

`

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import CoreLocationUI
import MapKit
class LocationButtonViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private lazy var manager = CLLocationManager()
    private static let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.008, longitudeDelta: 0.008)
    
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.408672852282024, longitude: -5.944668759610994), span: LocationButtonViewModel.span)
    @Published var fetchingLocation: Bool = false
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
    }
    
    func requestLocation() {
        fetchingLocation = true
        manager.requestLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first?.coordinate {
            region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: LocationButtonViewModel.span)
        }
        fetchingLocation = false
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
        fetchingLocation = false
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = LocationButtonViewModel()
        
        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Map(coordinateRegion: $model.region)
                    .overlay(
                        Group {
                        if model.fetchingLocation {
                            ProgressView()
                                .tint(.black)
                        } else {
                            LocationButton(.currentLocation) {
                                model.requestLocation()
                            }
                            .overlay(
                                Circle()
                                    .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                    .cornerRadius(22)
                    .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                    .symbolVariant(.fill)
                    .tint(.white)
                    .offset(x: proxy.size.width / 2 - 44, y: proxy.size.height / 2 - 64)
                    .padding()
                    )
            }
        }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the appropriate key:value pair to your info.plist file?

Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description : Message to display to users here

Comment: I had forgotten about the plist.
Thank you very much